# "Cube doesn't exist" when executing a query in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms, ssas-tabular

I have AW2019 database backup and I am creating a SQL Server tabular project from the VS2019. In VS2019, after I successfully build & deploy the solution after importing the database, I can see all the tables listed in SSAS database opened on ssms. But then if I try to make a new query like `SELECT * FROM [TabularProject1].[HumanResources].[Employee]`, I get an error:

> The HumanResources cube does not exist.

Why is this happening?

As per my understanding (I am new to this...), cubes are mdm OLAPS and tabular are relational tables. I have tabular instance and I am creating a tabular model. Then why it is quoting a "cube"?

And if I were to write only the column part, i.e, `SELECT * FROM [Sales SalesOrderDetail]`, I get the error:

> Either the user, 'DELL\milapm', does not have permission to access the
> referenced mining model, 'Sales SalesOrderDetail', or the object does
> not exist.

Please tell me where I am wrong and what should be done. Eli5 if possible, it would be huge help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you use an OLAP driver instead of an SQL DB Engine driver in the data source of your tabular model. Make sure you have something like `"Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=..."` in your connection string. The current driver interprets your statement as MDX and not as SQL.